# How to get POST parameter in twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a url of a twig page like that :

```
  /frontend?id=2
```

How I can get the value 2 in twig page directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not POST parameter but a GET parameter.

You could get it by in twig template.

```
app.request.get('id')
```

Comment: only when u have app setup (or using symfony)

Answer (score 5):

While this is technically possible (as mentioned by @xdazz), the short answer is that you don't. The reason that you use a templating system--and even specific templating markup--is that **you should never be echoing content from the user straight back out**.

Security, separation of concerns, readability, and other reasons come to mind.

It's true that Symfony's HTTP foundation does a lot of sanitization for you, and twig is quite good at escaping; even so, it's best not to add exposure for no reason. Use a controller to pull data out of the request, feed it to the proper model(s), and populate DAOs that you can then push into your twig templates.

Comment: The comment doesn't make any sense. TWIG templates can and do display GET parameters or something derived from them. Security nothing. It's a visible GET parameter.

Comment: It's not about protecting user information that is in the GET, but about preventing all kinds of XSS and other attack vectors by not echoing unsanitized input.